# UI bootstrap modal does not show up in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using UI Bootstrap modal but i am facing some issue with it.

When i click the button the the modal appears but it is not visible and when i click somewhere else on screen to close modal it shows me some weird error.

[Here modal has appeared but not visible and when i click somewhere else on screen to close modal the red error in inspect screen shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBMqr.png)
[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9j16.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle 'Possibly unhandled rejection: backdrop click' in a general way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416570/how-to-handle-possibly-unhandled-rejection-backdrop-click-in-a-general-way)

Comment: As you can see in code , there is no duplication and before that the problem is why does modal does not appear even though i had divided code into head , body and footer.