# angular-ui-router-uib-modal: reload page below when click outside the modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui-router-uib-modal and I have a question on it.
When I close my modal (which confirm a successfull/failed operation), I need to reload page below (that show a list of data). As shown in the example below, I can specify that behavior in 'Close' button and also in 'X symbol' to close modal (with the `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"`).
But... How can I specify the same operation when a user clicks outisde the modal and automatically closes the modal itself?

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="bb8-modal-close" ui-sref="home.gestioneFondi({gestione:true, innescatoDaMenuLaterale:false})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">
            <span class="visuallyhidden glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"/>
        </div>
        <h4 class="modal-title modal-title-font">Info</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" ng-switch="esito">
        <p class="text-center modal-body-font" ng-switch-when="true">Success</p>
        <p class="text-center modal-body-font" ng-switch-when="false">Error</p>
    </div>  
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="home.gestioneFondi({gestione:true, innescatoDaMenuLaterale:false})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Chiudi</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: I find an answer seeing this post (and the Malcor's reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416570/how-to-handle-possibly-unhandled-rejection-backdrop-click-in-a-general-way)

Answer (score 0):

So when you open a modal like this it is returning the promise:

> var modalInstance = $modal.open({..});

you can specify the modal closing event on the promise

> modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {..});

You can specify below code to reload the state.

> $state.reload();

For above to work, you have to inject `$state` dependency in your controller.

> app.controller('controller', ['$state',function($state){..}])